# Learning Git, Stuck After "git merge --no-ff feature/signup-form"

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

I'm working through a Git tutorial and it's asked me to merge this file using the --no-ff options but now I'm stuck in a place like this:

```
    Mackenzies-MacBook-Pro:learn-git Mackenzie$ git merge --no-ff feature/signup-form

Merge branch 'feature/signup-form'
added signup

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
-- INSERT --
```

I'm not sure where/what to type and the tutorial doesn't reference this at all.

Comment: Looks like vim, hit `ESC` and then type `:wq`

Comment: Have you used Vi or Vim before?  You need to hit escape to get to command mode, then type: `:wq` to exit and save your message.  If you're interested in learning more, check out vimtutor or any number of other Vim tutorials (vimtutor is nice because it's built-in).

Comment: Didn't do anything. I've been working in MacOS' Terminal though, I think that means not vim, right?

Comment: Ah That did it! Don't know how I didn't think to hit ESC. Thanks!